# Django Bulk_create for inserting Excel into the postgresql database

Tags: python, django, pandas, nginx, django-models

Im using `pandas` in django app to read and process 3 excel files with about 1000 rows in each file .

Also I have 3 models with 10-15 fields. so i decided to make 3 arrays of objects and use `bulk_create` to insert them into the database .

The problem is it takes too long to process and most times `nginx` raises `504 timeout error` .

Is this the correct way to insert excel to database ?

isn't it better to broke data in some parts then use bulk_create to insert them ? 
for example 10 parts with 100 data in each one .

Now server cpu is used 80-95 percent while processing and database engine is busy & engaged !!

Answer (score 1):

[`bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create) is a good solution, but it has a few caveats, as I'm sure you've found.

First, it defaults to inserting *all* of the items in the array at one shot. If you're dumping 10k inserts at once with a number of indices, it'll require some time for the db to absorb and rebuild the indices.  Alternatively, you can use the `batch_size` param to chunk the inserts into smaller pieces, which could be more agreeable by your db.

You may not have noticed the equivalent in the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html), specifically `chunksize`

So chances are good the entire issue is you're overwhelming your db, and need to optimize how you send it the data for inserts.